# How to prevent user registration form in Django from returning password field can not be null

Tags: python, django, forms

I have created a user registration form in Django but every time I test it, the user is not being saved to the database because when the password is entered it raises "this field can not be null. I do not understand why this is happening since the form was working before, and it follows the same procedures as other registration forms. I have been trying to figure out the cause of the issue for days and I am still not  understanding how the field can be null and still wont work. However in the terminal I am not getting any error messages, and the login form is working because users are created via the admin. Thanks for the help and  here is the code I am using.

## the user form

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email already exists.")
        return email

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        username_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if username_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username already exists.")
        return username

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        if len(password) <= 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be longer than 8 characters")
        else:
            print("password saved")
```

## My view registration function

```
def register_view(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, new_user)
                return redirect('/appname/account/')
    return render(request, "appname/index.html", {"form": form})
```

## My html

```
% block signup %}
  <div clss="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <h1>appname</h1>
        <p>x and x</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3>Sign Up</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'appname:index' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form }}
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign Up"/>
            </form>

            <h5>Have an Account? <a href="{% url 'appname:login' %}">Login</a></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clean a django form field (using `def clean_myfield`) you need to return that field

```
def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    if len(password) <= 8:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be longer than 8 characters")
    else:
        print("password saved")
    return password  #  <--  add this line
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much that fixed it. It makes sense now since I added that function after the time when the registration was working. Appreciate it.

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg glad to help - if that fixes the problem - please mark that this is the solution to your question. thanks